# Writing data frame to file in R

Tags: r, format, dataframe

I created the following data frame:

```
VAL1 <- c(0.56972, 0.98741, 0.12547)
VAL2 <- c(0.12345, 0.34532, 0.34234)

DF  <- data.frame(time_UTC=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2007-02-25 00:00"),
               to=as.POSIXct("2007-02-26 23:00"),
               by="1 hours"), VAL)

head(DF)
         time_UTC    VAL1    VAL2
1 2007-02-25 00:00:00 0.56972 0.12345
2 2007-02-25 01:00:00 0.98741 0.34532
3 2007-02-25 02:00:00 0.12547 0.34234
4 2007-02-25 03:00:00 0.56972 0.12345
5 2007-02-25 04:00:00 0.98741 0.34532
6 2007-02-25 05:00:00 0.12547 0.34234
```

How can I write to file (with `write.csv`) the rest of the columns (VAL1 and VAL2) in a scientific format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `options(scipen=)` before writing to csv. See `?options` for details.

```
options(scipen=-3)
> print(10000)
[1] 1e+04

options(scipen=3)
> print(1e5)
[1] 100000
```

Comment: `options(digits=2)`
`> print(999)`
`[1] 1e+03`. I don't know how to get decimal.